# Add Custom onClick Event Listener on Array Index in React Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array defined globally trying to add custom event listener to each of the element present in array

```
var item = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
export default class Test extends React.Component{
   componentWillMount() {
      for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
         item[i].addEventListener("click",this.bindClick.bind(this,i));
      }
   }

    bindClick(i){
        console.log("check", i)
    }
}
```

I have tried above code but i am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: item[i].addEventListener is not a function
```

please help me, Thanks in advance;

Comment: You can't add an event listener on one of those array elements, since it's not a DOM node.

Comment: then what should i do now

Comment: As Dragos said, item in array is string, and it has to be HTML element (DOM node) to use addEventListener function. Because string object does not have that property by default.

Comment: is there any way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can’t add an even listener to the items, because they are string types => which dont have a ‘addEventListener’ method. But you can wrap the array elements with a React element, which you can easily bind an event listener to:

```
const arrayItems = [<div key=“0” onClick={this.bindClick}>A</div>];
```

So your component will look like:

```
export default class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super(props);

        this.bindClick = this.bindClick.bind(this);
    }

    bindClick() {
        console.log(“hello!”)
    }

    render() {

        const arrayItems = [
            <div key=“0” onClick={this.bindClick}>A</div> ,
            <div key=“1” onClick={this.bindClick}>B</div>
        ];

        return arrayItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this, this time i am not getting the same error but things are not working as i required

Comment: i just made a modification to above code (added the constructor(){}) section, give it a try now, i think that should work

Comment: strange! any chance you could copy paste your entire file?

Comment: sorry my bad, it works i am getting "Hello" in my console thanks.